# Kendo UI :- Kendo Scheduler disable time slots of a single day view, other than saved event in a day

Tags: configuration, kendo-ui, scheduled-tasks, kendo-scheduler

My question also similarly same to this [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525110/kendo-ui-scheduler-disable-multiple-time-span-range-of-a-single-day) which some one already asked in stack-overflow forum.I am doing a customization of a kendo scheduler based on our requirement,what i am trying to do is creating a scheduler which will be used by some admin and visible to get info to the normal users. Admin will scheduled an event for the particular day for particular time period, the user can able to see the scheduled events but he can't allowed to create a another event in that day. 
Now what my requirement is after he/she done with saving an event in kendo scheduler ,the remaining time slots of that day has to be disabled other than already created event time slots.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/forums/disable-scheduler-double-click-edit-window-without-to-disable-drag-and-drop

i think this may help you

All you need is to reconfigure the kendo Scheduler using the jquery as per your required event

If it helps you please mark as answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. and Sorry to say your answer is not related to my question.what i am trying to ask is " if i created an event in a particular time duration. After creating that event,the remaining time slots belongs to that day which i already created on event ,must be disable:. i hope you understood my requirement.